# CrashLoopBackError when running microservices of an application in Kubernetes containers

Tags: kubernetes, digital-ocean

When try to run microservices of thingsboard on Digital Ocean kubernetes cluster the container status shows CrashLoopBackofError. Why??

Answer (score 0):

Check if this is similar to [`thingsboard/thingsboard` issue 2838](https://github.com/thingsboard/thingsboard/issues/2838), assuming you have [followed this guide](https://github.com/thingsboard/thingsboard/blob/master/k8s/README.md):

> Now with release-2.5 (self-built release-2.5 branch images) or master (latest images), micro-services still deploy fine, but tb-node are falling into `CrashLoopBackOff`.

> in case of tb-node, this looks like missing `TB_QUEUE_TYPE` env var in the container / deployment definition, after adding it the service starts without complaining.
> It does not fix transport services though, something else may be missing there...

> OK, after removing
>
> ```
>    - name: TB_SERVICE_TYPE
>      value: "monolith"
> ```
>
> from deployment definitions of transport services, all services are now starting...